# jquery function not redirecting url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am working with codeigniter and jquery. I am using ajax to send some info to a codeigniter function to perform a db operation , in order to update the page. After the operation is complete I am trying to refresh the page. However the refresh works inconsistently and usually I have to reload the page manually. I see no errors in firebug:

```
           var message = $('#send_message').val()
               if ((searchIDs).length>0){
                   alert("searchIDs "+searchIDs );
               $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "AjaxController/update",
                   data:{ i : searchIDs, m : message },                        
                   dataType: 'json',
                   success: function(){
                       alert("OK");
                   },
                   complete: function() {
                        location.href = "pan_controller/my_detail";
                   }
               })
               .done(function() { // echo url in "/path/to/file" url
                // redirecting here if done
                alert("OK");
                location.href = "pan_controller/my_detail";
                });

                } else { alert("nothing checked") }
              break;
```

How can I fix this?

addendum: I tried changing to ;

```
  $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "AjaxController/update",
                   data:{ i : searchIDs, m : message },                        
                   dataType: 'json',
                   .done(function() { // echo url in "/path/to/file" url
                    // redirecting here if done
                        alert("REFRESHING..");
                        location.href = "pan_controller/my_detail";
                    });
                  }
               })
```

This is just defaulting to the website homepage. again, no errors in firebug

Comment: wrong thinking of me

Comment: try prepending a slash in your url like so: `location.href = "/pan_controller/my_detail";`

Comment: Is your server action returning an error in some cases?

Comment: you are mixing a whole lot of things.... `.done()` is the newer version of `success()`. you have __both__. use `.done()` and remove the deprecated `success()`.

Comment: Please see addendum above:

Comment: disable the alerts. Display messages via diaolg() and redirect in OK-button function.

Answer (score 1):

Add the window object on `location.href` like this:

```
window.location.href = "pan_controller/my_detail";
```

Comment: Sorry, this did not help. Again, this database update does occur its just that page refresh does not and I have to do this manually. Its working as expected on my local wamp but when I push to my shared hosting folder it seems to work sometimes only.

Comment: on shared hosting i think you should also include the host

Answer (score 1):

Try to use full path like

```
$.ajax({a
               type: "POST",
               url: "YOURBASEPATH/AjaxController/update",
               data:{ i : searchIDs, m : message },                        
               dataType: 'json',
               .done(function() { // echo url in "/path/to/file" url
                // redirecting here if done
                    alert("REFRESHING..");
                    location.href = "YOURBASEPATH/pan_controller/my_detail";
                });
              }
           })
```

BASEPATH should be like this "http://www.example.com"

Comment: Hi Shaiful, I finally it working the way you suggested, after some confusion on my part in working with javascript variables. Thanks for your efforts and your comments on the other questions. As it turned out I can see that a refresh is happening, but a reload of the database is not occuring, so I'm starting to think that this may be some sort of DB or ORM problem. I'm upvoting you because it is a good idea even though it doesn't help in this case. Regards - Bill

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the csrf_enabled (config/config.php) and trying it. If that works, then re-enable the protection and, instead of compiling data yourself, serialize the form; or, at least include the csrf hidden field codeigniter automatically adds. You can also use GET to avoid the CSRF protection, but that's least advisable of of the solutions.