# Why are success function commands are not executed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

[image]

I am working with codeigniter and jquery ajax. I'm having some incosistencies b/w my app locally on wamp (working perfectly) and my deployed app (not so much). I'm trying to figure this out. as part of my experimentation I realixed that with the following code:'

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Ajax/updateReplies",
    data:{ i : searchIDs, m : message },                        
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(){
        console.log("hi");
        window.location.href = "controller/reply";
    }
```

when the button is clicked, I can see in firebug that the ajax request worked and data was submitted to the backend codeigniter function, but neither of the 2 success function commands are executed.

Why not?

Comment: depends on issues you haven't identified like response status, valid json return etc. Provide more feedback from console

Comment: The problem might be on the server side. You might try to add an error function in your ajax call to understand what is going on.

Comment: Is this your full $.ajax code or you missed the closing `});` part when pasting here?

Comment: I think you asked same question before here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699629/jquery-function-not-redirecting-url/26701988#26701988 and the answer is you need to full path of redirection for window.location.href.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you set an ajax request to receive **json** data through the attribute **dataType** you must make sure that the data is formatted properly, otherwise you will run into an error.

try to check if the call runs into any issue with:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Ajax/update",
    data:{ i : searchIDs, m : message },                        
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(){
        console.log("hi");
        window.location.href = "controller/reply";
    },
    //important
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
        alert(err.Message);
    }
});
```

As a last resort, which i **do not** recommend, you could set **dataType** to *'text'*, and avoid any formatting issues

Comment: Thanks for looking at this Valerio -  I've added a screenshot to give some more info. I see an error it says "SyntaxError: missing ) in parenthetical"

Comment: Unfortunately i am no expert about that error, but i have just read an interesting [stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18242512/missing-in-parenthetical-error-but-everything-seems-to-be-closed-off-properly) to a similar problem. it seems ths could be an encoding issue